# Prove that if binary relation  is an interval order

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binary

Prove that if binary relation  is an interval order, then $$ xPy \Rightarrow yP \subseteq xP. $$

Comment: You really ought to include a definition of $xP$, as you did in your earlier question: if $P$ is a relation on $A$, then $xP=\{a\in A:x\,P\,a\}$.

Comment: This follows immediately from the fact that an interval order is a partial order and therefore is transitive.